# How do you access information in a hash reference that has been passed to a sub-routine?

Tags: perl

I am trying to use hash references to pass information to sub-routines.  Psuedo code:

```
sub output_detail {
    Here I want to be able to access each record by the key name (ex. "first", "second", etc)
}

sub output_records {
    I want to use a foreach to pass each record has reference to another sub-routine
    that handles each record.

    foreach $key ( sort( keys %someting) ) {
        output_detail(something);
    }
}

%records = ();

while ($recnum, $first, $second, $third) = db_read($handle)) {
    my %rec = ("first"=>$first, "second"=>$second, "third=>$third);
    my $id = $recnum;
    $records{$id} = \%rec;
}

output_records(\%records);
```

I'm not sure how to de-reference the hashes when passed to a sub-routine.
Any ideas would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use `->` to access keys of a hash ref. So, your argument to output_records will come through as a scalar hash ref.

```
sub output_records {
    my $records = shift;
    my $first = $records->{"first"};
}
```

See [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) for more info.

Comment: OK.  Using your sample code I was able to play around with my code and get it to work!  The problem is I wasn't using the '->' de-reference arrow correctly.

Comment: Sorry! I keep hitting the return key!  I'm not sure how to move down a line without hitting the Enter key.  Anyway, here it is. 'sub output_detail {
 
 my ($outrec) = @_;
 
 print $outrec->{'first'};
 print $outrec->{'second'};
 print $outrec->{'third'};
}

sub output_records {

 my ($outrecsref) = @_;
 
 foreach $key ( sort (keys %$outrecsref) ) {
  output_detail($outrecsref->{$key});
 }
}'

Comment: I am truly sorry about these comments.  Let me try it again. `sub output_detail {
 
 my ($outrec) = @_;
 
 print $outrec->{'first'};
 print $outrec->{'second'};
 print $outrec->{'third'};
}

sub output_records {

 my ($outrecsref) = @_;
 
 foreach $key ( sort (keys %$outrecsref) ) {
  output_detail($outrecsref->{$key});
 }
}
`

Comment: Oh well!  Hopefully you haven't contracted a headache by now.

Comment: I enjoyed that. In the future, you can just edit your question with an update.

Answer (score 0):

```
sub output_detail {
    my $hash = shift;
    my $value = $$hash{some_key};
}

sub output_records {
    my $hash = shift;

    foreach my $key (sort keys %$hash) {
        output_detail($hash, $key);  
        # or just pass `$$hash{$key}` if you only need the value
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm so used to using `$hash->{some_key}` that your example comes as a bit of a surprise. Is there any practical difference between `$$hash{some_key}` and `$hash->{some_key}`?

Comment: `$$hash{key}` and `$hash->{key}` are exactly the same.  Doubled sigil dereferencing of elements uses the same structure as full `%$hash` and slice `@$hash{qw/a b/}` dereferencing, and is one character shorter, so it is always my preference.  A corollary to that is that I prefer to only use `->` to mean "call" as in `$obj->method` or `$obj->(...)`